# Avoid cannot pass reference error in function

Tags: php, function, reference

I have a function where an argument is passed with a reference (&). However, if i set that argument to NULL, i get the error:

"Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference in..."

This is the script:

```
<?php
function doSomething(&$reference,$arg1,$arg2){
    if($reference !== NULL){
        //Do something with reference

    }else{
        //Do something else
    }
}

//Call with reference
doSomething($a,$b,$c);

//Call without reference
//doSomething(NULL,$b,$c);
?>
```

This is i think due to the fact that NULL is not declared as a variable, but immediately declared in the function itself. It works when i do this:

```
$nullVar = NULL;
doSomething($nullVar,$b,$c);
```

How do i edit my function so it will not show the reference error when i just put NULL in the function, and only keeps the reference when possible (since i do not use the reference when it is set to NULL)

Comment: I think you can't avoid this - only variables can be passed by reference and NULL is not a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still create an optional reference if you swap the positions of the arguments:

```
function doSomething($arg1,$arg2, &$reference = null){
    if($reference !== NULL){
        //Do something with reference

    }else{
        //Do something else
    }
}

$a = 'a';
$b = 'b';

doSomething($a, $b);
```

But passing `null` to that third argument will still cause an error.

```
doSomething($a, $b, null); // error
```

Also references can be satisfied by newly created variables.  Since variables without assigned values are by default `null`, you can provide a variable without any intention of using it afterwards.

```
doSomething($a, $b, $unused_var);
```

Comment: This is only a simple example, but this would still not work when there are for example 2 reference arguments.

Comment: @user3053216 Updated to give you an idea of how to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

You cant reference NULL, it doesn't exist. Honestly, check for null before you call the function and run the if($reference !== NULL) block. or you can split the function into two separate functions, one if $reference is null and the other for $reference pointing to something.